# TypeScript file paths aren't working when I try to bootstrap Angular app using esbuild

Tags: angular, typescript, esbuild

I have set up `jsbundling-rails` with `esbuild` on a Rails 6 app with the goal of running Angular. The TypeScript compilation seems to be working fine, and I've copied in the official starter application. But when I try to run it, the file paths don't load right.

This is all happening in the `app/javascript` directory that `esbuild` uses. `angular_admin` is just a directory I created because it's supposed to hold the angular app that's supposed to do some admin things in the future. Here are relevant portions of the files in question:

**app/javascript/application.js**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './angular_admin/app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**app/javascript/angular_admin/app/app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; // this and other angular imports work

import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; // this seems to work?

// more angular stuff goes here
```

**app/javascript/angular_admin/app/app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html', // danger, will robinson!
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] // danger!
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

So it works up until it gets to `app.component.ts`, but the HTML and CSS files alluded to there don't load. I get these errors in my browser:

```
GET http://FOO.BAR/app.component.html 404 (Not Found)
Failed to load ./app.component.html
GET http://FOO.BAR/app.component.css 404 (Not Found)
```

(`FOO.BAR` represents the domain name of the app)

So it's just trying to get those files by plain old HTTP requests and it isn't getting them. They exist in the filesystem though, I promise. But I get the same result if I delete them.

Edit: I found [this page](https://how-to.dev/how-to-build-angular-cli-application-with-esbuild) that explains how to fix it

Comment: files are bundled. you aren't expected to query these files at all.

Comment: Yeah that's great but it doesn't tell me how to fix it.

Comment: you are supposed to navigate to the url using the route that you define in app.module not navigate directly to app.component.html which is not allowed you to access it directly

Comment: you should not ever open site.com/app.cpomponent.html, but open just site.com or site.com/index.html

Comment: I'm not _trying_ to open site.com/app.component.html, that's the problem. I'm trying to refer to a file during the compile process, but it thinks I'm looking for another resource after compile.